# OCaml - Communication from a server to the thread that spawned it

Tags: multithreading, unix, events, ocaml, client-server

Given a server that receives connections from clients, does some work, then after the nth connection is shutdown, it either shuts down itself or starts ignoring connections by doing nothing when the clients connect. I want the thread that established the server to wait for the server to communicate that information (that it has closed its nth connection) to continue its execution.

Expected behaviour:

```ml
let t = Thread.create (Unix.establish_server loop) addr in
f1 ();
wait_for_loop_signal ();
f2 ();
```

---

I tried doing that with `Thread.join` in that case I would need to kill/stop the thread `t` to continue:

```ml
let t = Thread.create (Unix.establish_server loop) addr in
f1 ();
Thread.join ();
f2 ();
```

But it doesn't work, because `loop` is executed on a separate thread after each connection. So the code of `loop` is executed on child threads spawned by `establish_server`. And the thread on which `establish_server` is executed in not accessible from `loop` unless there is a way for a thread to kill its parent.

---

Using Event, by having `loop` send a message through a channel provided by the initial thread, with `Event.sync (Event.send channel ())`:

```ml
let channel = Event.new_channel () in 
let t = Thread.create (Unix.establish_server (loop channel)) addr in
f1 ();
let _ = Event.sync (Event.receive channel) in
f2 ();
```

But in this case, the execution blocks at `let _ = Event.sync (Event.receive channel) in`. The `send` is called correctly and get executed inside loop. But the message that was sent through the channel never gets read by `receive`. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `Unix.establish_server` launches a new process and not a thread for each connection. Since the server forks new processes with separate memory, the only way to communicate is trough an inter-process communication mechanism, for instance another socket. Neither `Thread.join` nor `Events` can be used meaningfully with `establish_server`. Similarly, there is no shared memory between the various connections.

In other words, if you want more control on the server, the function `establish_server` is not the one that you are looking for.

Comment: I did notice that `Unix.establish_server` forks the process but I didn't know that it implied that communication can't happen. Are there any libs/tools that can be used instead of `establish_server` to run a server that you can control? Or using another socket is the way to go?

Comment: The function `establish_server` is implemented in a  little more than 20 lines of code https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/otherlibs/unix/unix_unix.ml#L1092 . If you want to learn how to write your own server (since you are nor using a library), it might a good starting point for writing your own function.